# How to make double Python for loop to interpolate faster

Tags: python, numpy, loops

Is there any way to make a double `for` loop faster in Python?
The double loop shown below uses the numpy interpolation over different dimensions.

I want to interpolate the vertical dimension of several matrices which are 3 dimensional (pressure, latitude, longitude).

The original data has the dimension `[0,z,k,l]`, where `z` is pressure for 72 levels and I want them to be 32 levels. Variables are data from reanalysis files, which are `ps_p42` (surface pressure (0, lat, lon)), `plev` is sigma-pressure which needs to be computed at the beginning. `PS_v72` are pressure levels at 72 levels. Then I want to regrid `U`, `V`, `T`, `Q`, and `RH` from 72 levels to 42 levels and at the end get all those new profiles saved in a netCDF. My code works, but the double `for` loop with interpolation for each variable is slow.

Originally, this following loop works, but for the data I am using it takes at least **26** minutes to complete:

```py
plev = np.zeros([32,192,288])
U_v32 = np.zeros([32,192,288])
V_v32 = np.zeros([32,192,288])
T_v32 = np.zeros([32,192,288])
Q_v32 = np.zeros([32,192,288])
RH_v32 = np.zeros([32,192,288])

for k in range(0, 192):  # latitude
    for l in range(0, 288):  # longitude

        plev[:,k,l] = hyam[:] * 1000.0 + hybm[:] * ps_p42.values[0,k,l]

        U_v32[:,k,l] = np.interp(plev[:,k,l], PS_v72.values[0,:,k,l], U_v72.values[0,:,k,l])
        V_v32[:,k,l] = np.interp(plev[:,k,l], PS_v72.values[0,:,k,l], V_v72.values[0,:,k,l]) 
        T_v32[:,k,l] = np.interp(plev[:,k,l], PS_v72.values[0,:,k,l], T_v72.values[0,:,k,l])
        Q_v32[:,k,l] = np.interp(plev[:,k,l], PS_v72.values[0,:,k,l], Q_v72.values[0,:,k,l])
        RH_v32[:,k,l] = np.interp(plev[:,k,l], PS_v72.values[0,:,k,l], RH_v72.values[0,:,k,l])
```

Comment: What are the variables? If it is 3D, why not interpolate the surface rather than many lines?

Comment: Variables are data from reanalysis files, which are ps_p42 (surface pressure(0,lat lon)), plev is sigma-pressure which needs to be computed at the beginning. PS_v72 are pressure levels at 72 levels. Then I want to regrid U, V, T, Q and RH from 72 levels to 42 levels and at the end get all those new profiles saved in a netCDF. Which already works but is that double for loop and the interpolation for each variable what it makes it slow.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot interpolate the 3D data and avoid the explicit (i.e. python) loops?

Comment: why don't you edit the question and add that extra  info

Comment: @jared I only need to interpolate the dimension corresponding to the vertical dimension.

Comment: you are doing the interpolation 300k times, that is 5ms per interpolation, not bad. You can only gain performance with multi core, but Python has the GIL that prevents it done in 1 process, start multiple python interpreters, each does a section of range-k and at the end combine the results, communicate over sockets, no need to use files, or send each `[:,k,l]` result to a collector process

Comment: be aware Python is not a fast language, numpy does the heavy calculation (C++), is numpy doing the slicing or Python

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can be done using 3D interpolation. If you add some representative data to your example then I can try and see if it will work.

Comment: if written in C/C++ how fast is an interpolation from 72 to 32 points, why are `k,l` the last indices, if you have `k,l,z` the result of the interpolation is contiguous, in C++ no need to do some complex copying, the interpolation function saves in the result array, can also be done by giving a stride to the interpolation function